# retry sql connection using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, activex, activexobject

I know using javascript is not the best way to connect to a SQL server but this is for an in-house application.  I connect using the following:

```
dbNSConnection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;
var sNSConnectionString="Driver={SQL Server};TrustedConnection=Yes;Server=" + sNSServer + ";Database=" + sNSDatabase + ";UID=" + sNSUID + ";PWD=" + sNSPWD;
dbNSConnection.Open(sNSConnectionString);
```

How can I make sure connection has gone thru and how do I retry if not connected?

Comment: This is part of an HTA.  What happens is there are three separate SQL connections onload.  If the connections hang, or don't connect, I would like to retry connecting.

Comment: If `TrustedConnection=Yes` is used, any credentials passed with `UID`  will be ignored

Comment: There's [`ConnectComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676126%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event available for `Connection` object.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there any other way you could get this done on the codebehind, and pass the results to the javascript? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234447/how-to-trap-an-error-and-save-error-detail-in-database-and-redirect-to-custom-er) may be an example of what I'm talking about originally.

If not, can't you simply do the following?

```
try
  {
    dbNSConnection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;
    var sNSConnectionString="Driver={SQL Server};TrustedConnection=Yes;Server=" + sNSServer + ";Database=" + sNSDatabase + ";UID=" + sNSUID + ";PWD=" + sNSPWD;
    dbNSConnection.Open(sNSConnectionString);
    //Run rest of query here
  }
catch(err)
  {
    var message = err.message;
    //Finish building errors message here
  }
```